# Compute coordinates position with projection

Tags: coordinates, openlayers, postgis

Given 2 coordinates (point 1 and 2 in red) in WGS84 I need to find the coordinates of the point perpendicular (point 3) to the line at a given distance.
I could manage to make the math to compute this perpendicular point, but when displayed on the map, the point seems to be at a wrong place, probably because of the projection.
What I want on a map:
[image]

And what I have instead on the map:

[image]

How can I take into account the projection so that the point on the map appears perpendicular to the line? The algorithm below to compute the point comes from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93424/calculate-rectangle-coordinates-from-line-and-height

```
public static Coords ComputePerpendicularPoint(Coords first, Coords last, double distance)
        {
            double slope = -(last.Lon.Value - first.Lon.Value) / (last.Lat.Value - first.Lat.Value);

            // number of km per degree = ~111km (111.32 in google maps, but range varies between 110.567km at the equator and 111.699km at the poles)
            // 1km in degree = 1 / 111.32km = 0.0089
            // 1m in degree = 0.0089 / 1000 = 0.0000089
            distance = distance * 0.0000089 / 100; //0.0000089 => represents around 1m in wgs84. /100 because distance is in cm

            double t = distance / Math.Sqrt(1 + (slope * slope));
            Coords perp_coord = new Coords();
            perp_coord.Lon = first.Lon + t;
            perp_coord.Lat = first.Lat + (t * slope);
           
            return perp_coord;
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would it be possible to do this in postgis directly? With some ideas taken from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251172/making-perpendicular-lines-through-each-polygon-edge-using-postgis it should be fairly easy

Comment: As well as angles being dependent on the projection the calculation seems flawed.  km per degree applies only to latitude as longitudes converge at the poles (0 km per degree).  If the distances are relatively small and not in polar regions it would be easier to calculate in view projection.  Use `getPointResolution(projection, 1, point, 'm')` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_proj.html#.getPointResolution to find what one view projection unit represents on the ground at your point 2.